# Why is it called a "healing factor"?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

Wikipedia and Marvel both list wolverines main mutation as a Healing Factor. A healing factor of...what? 2? 3? Over 9000?

Every time I've used the term 'factor' in the sense of it describing something (ie Warp Factor) it always has a scale attached to it. Is this true for Wolverine's ability?

If not, them why isn't his power simply called 'accelerated healing'?

Comment: And why do people say turn up the volume when they really mean turn up the intensity?

Comment: @KevinHowell is volume not: [The amplitude or loudness of a sound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/volume)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**His power IS defined as hyper-accelerated healing.**

The phrase "healing factor" should be considered in light of the definition of the word factor:

- factor: *noun* - One of the elements contributing to a particular result or situation; example: Poverty is only one of the factors in crime.

The term "healing factor" is not about a mathematical expression, per se, this is more of an accepted euphemism.

Comment: Thaddeus has the right of it. Here are a few more examples of factors: [Growth factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_factor) [Transforming growth factor beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transforming_growth_factor_beta) [Nerve growth factor signaling, neuroprotection, and neural repair.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11520933) [Tumor necrosis factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumor_necrosis_factors)

Comment: Another definition of factor: Something that helps produce or influence a result : one of the things that cause something to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's because they aren't as mathematical as you are. The same goes for when people say 100%. 100% of what? A percentage means nothing if not applied to something. Along those lines, it should be called a healing multiple, because a factor is a part of something. SO, like you said the only reason it should be called a factor is if we know the factor, and if the "Factor" is considered the basis of healing. i.e. his factor is 5 versus a non-mutant factor of 1, and these factors are multiplied to a universal healing amount.